# useEffect not seeing dependency change on single click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am making a call to an Api using the following hook. It returns 10 pictures at a time.

```
export const useFetchData = (url, page) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        const res = await axios.get(*****);
        const data = await res.data
        setApiData(data)
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [page, url])
  return { apiData, loading, error }
}
```

I am trying to do pagination in the following component by changing the state value of page by using the nextPage and backPage functions.

```
  let [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  let { apiData, loading, error } = useFetchData(url, page);
  const nextPage = () => {
    setPage(page ++);
  };
  const backPage = () => {
    setPage(page --);
  };

  return (
       <div className="photo-display__buttons-container">
          <button onMouseDown={()=>backPage()}>Back</button>
          <button onClick={()=>nextPage()}>Next</button>
        </div>
      <main className="photo-display">
        <div className="photo-display__container">
          {apiData?.photos.map((photo) => (
            <Photo key={photo.id} photo={photo} />
          ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

By extensive console logging I am able to see that the state value is changed and the hook is called but the try catch does not execute on a single click.

Only if it is double clicked does the try catch execute. The state value is temporarily changed to reflect the double increase but after the hook is called in goes back to the correct value.

Why? and How do i get it to work on a single click?

Comment: If you use existing state in a set state, you should use the callback/function version. `setPage(pg => pg++);`  (you might need parens or something there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `setPage` you are using a postfix `++`, which means the original value will be returned (and *then* incremented). You need to use a prefix `++` so that it is incremented first, then passed in to `setState`, or just skip the `++` entirely and do `setState(i + 1)`.

Eg (postfix):

```js
let i = 0;
console.log(i++);
```

Eg (prefix):

```js
let i = 0;
console.log(++i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `setPage(page ++)` to `setPage(page+1)`.